# Using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), can you access the ApplicationContext object?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

I have a Spring test that uses:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Unlike the older way of testing, extending from the Spring test base classes, there appears to be no obvious way to access to the ApplicationContext that has been loaded by Spring using `@ContextConfiguration`

How can I access the `ApplicationContext` object from my test methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Integration Testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing) section of the Spring Documentation

> @Autowired ApplicationContext
>
> As an alternative to implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface, you can inject  the application context for your test class through the @Autowired annotation on either a field or setter method. For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  // class body...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an @Autowired attribute of ApplicationContext

```
@Autowired ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class MyClassTest
{
}
```

and go to project build path `-> Source ->` add the location of your `applicationContext.xml`

I use maven so the `applicationContext.xml` is under `src/main/resources`.

If you use this method you can have a multiple applicationContext for testing
for example :

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext_Test.xml")
```

or

```
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:applicationContext_V01.xml")
```